# Match cell in sheet A to index in sheet B

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have 2 sheets.  The first sheet is where clients enter event information.  One of the cells is where they enter the short name of the location.

The second sheet contains a list of addresses where one of the fields contains a string of all the venues available at that address.

What I would like to do in Sheet 1 in a the last column is take the value of the short name the user has entered, and do a search of sheet 2 against the column that contains the venues.

When a match is found, I would like it to return cell 4 of the same row (which is the 4th cell).

Below is what I have written in the first sheet, but no matter what I enter into the short name, it always returns the same result.

=IF(I2="","",VLOOKUP(I2,Venue!$A$2:$D$100,4))

Below are screenshots of my sheets.

[image: Main Sheet]

[image: Venue]

In this example, dh2 in cell I2 should return the value of D3 in the venue sheet in cell J2 of the main sheet.

Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=iferror(VLOOKUP(I2, Venue!$C:$D, 2, false), "")
```